# Best way to store oauth2 access token globally in django app?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0

I'm using django as a backend for my project that integrates with an oauth2-app. I have been able to get the access token, but I'm kind of confused by how I should store it. I want it to be secret, but it should be accessible by the backend when the administrator or other users are making requests from the frontend => then to the backend (load external app access token) => then to the external app.

I've tried storing it in the admin user-model, but then only the admin can access it (unless I get the admin user-model with every request? Seems kind of clunky)

I've also tried storing it with os.environ, but as far as I can understand, these get cleared out when the server restarts.

What would be the best way of implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

Django all-auth is a great package that can do this for you (https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

Simply add your social account providers like this:

```
# Provider specific settings
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'google': {
        # For each OAuth based provider, either add a ``SocialApp``
        # (``socialaccount`` app) containing the required client
        # credentials, or list them here:
        'APP': {
            'client_id': '123',
            'secret': '456',
            'key': ''
        }
    }
}
```

And add it's urls to your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: I’m familiar with allauth, but my app is not listed as under providers.